# How can I create a list of elements with the same xpath using selenium with python?

Tags: python, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need to click on several elements from the same table on the same webpage. I was thinking to do so with a for loop but in order to perform that action I first need to create a list of these elements.

```
//table[@border='1']//a
```

This is the xpath which selects all the elements from the table, how can I create a list of all these?

Comment: Simply use `find_elements_by_xpath()` instead of `find_element_by_xpath()`

Comment: You want to retrieve any attribute name from <a>?

Comment: @Andersson I am using this line of code to find all the elements: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//table[@border='1']//a']"))).click()  Would your method work by changing XPATH to XPATHS? And then how can i put all the elements in a list?

Comment: In this case you need to replace `EC.element_to_be_clickable` with `EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located`. Also remove `.click()`

Comment: @Andersson How can i put the elements in a list a this point? I've tried simply setting the method equal to a variable but it doesn't work and I think the error comes from the method

Comment: @IshitaShah No, I just need to store in a list 10 elements using the xpath which links them all

Comment: @LorenzoMussetti , `my_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@border='1']//a']")))`

Comment: @Andersson I get "TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:" at this line (By.XPATH, "//table[@border='1']//a']"))) could it be that i am missing the right method to select them? (I've broken down the last line of code in two for simplicity)

Comment: Share HTML sample for the same. Also check if `table` located inside an `iframe` (`...<iframe>...<table>...</table>...</iframe>...`)

Comment: @Andersson It is but I am already working into the frame so I don't think that's the problem

Comment: Update your question with your current code and HTML sample (page URL)

Comment: @Andersson https://ibb.co/deMrMo you should see a screenshot with the interested part of code here

Comment: @Andersson I fixed a bug in my code and now it works but only for the first iteration of the loop, i've used the loop in the answer below plus a line which makes m go back to the previous page:
   " for values in links:     
    values.click()     
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, "//a[@href='Javascript:history.go(-1)']"))).click()"

Comment: You cannot use same list if you move to another page as list elements becomes stale. Try to open new ticket regarding this new issue as it does not correlate with the current question

Comment: @Andersson ok thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While @SergiyKonoplyaniy answer was in the right direction, addressing your queries one by one:

- *How can I create a list of elements with the same xpath* : To create a *list of elements* you need to use [**`find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_elements_by_xpath) which will create a *List* of elements matching the *xpath* you have specified.
- Example:

  ```
  my_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@border='1']//a")
  ```
- *Need to click on several elements*: As you need to `click()` on several elements you have to iterate through all the elements you have captured in the *List* as follows:

  ```
  for link in my_links:
      link.click()
  ```
- Now the most important aspect is, as per your *xpath* `//table[@border='1']//a` each and every element:

  - Has 3 distinct stages interms of **presence**, **visibility** and **interactibility** (i.e. **clickability**)
  - To collect the elements in a *List* you should always invoke a waiter with *expected-conditions* as [**`visibility_of_all_elements_located(locator)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located) as follows:

    ```
    my_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@border='1']//a")))
    ```
  - The pseudo code as a solution for your question will be:

    ```
    my_links = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@border='1']//a")))
    for link in my_links:
        link.click()
    ```
  - For your future reference, if you intend to invoke `click()` on any particular element always invoke a waiter with *expected-conditions* as [**`element_to_be_clickable(locator)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) as follows:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "desired_element_xpath"))).click()
    ```

Comment: Thanks it is very exhausting even though we had solved that in the comments under the original question! If you want to help even further you can try to modify your answer to my other question :)

Comment: I am not sure why you felt _exhausting_ here, perhaps I have pointed you to all the required documentation necessary as per the suggested lines of code, methods and functionalities. Let me know if you need more help here.

Answer (score 3):

Use find_element**s** instead of find_element:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@border='1']//a")
for values in links:
    values.click()
```

Comment: Thanks, would you mind taking a look at the comments under the question and trying to adapt the code to that method?